# Regex: searching for words that starts with @ or @

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I want to create a regex in python that find words that start with @ or @.

I have created the following regex, but the output contains one extra space in each string as you can see

```
regex = r'\s@\/?[\w\.\-]{2,}'
exp = 'george want@to play @.hdgska football @dddada'
re.findall(regex, exp)
Output: [' @.hdgska', ' @dddada']
```

However, the output that I want to have is the following

```
Output: ['@.hdgska', '@dddada']
```

I would be grateful if you could help me!

**Edit:**
@The fourth bird, Thank you so much for your help. There is one more thing that I don't know how to deal with. In case that we have this string

```
s = "george want@to play @.hdgska football @dddada@snhfbjskjs"
```

the output is

```
['@.hdgska', '@dddada']
```

However, the output that I want should be one this

```
'@.hdgska'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pattern you are actually matching the leading `\s` and after the @ there can be an optional `/` with `\/?` but it should optionally start with a dot.

You could match for example an optional dot, and then 2 or more times the allowed characters in the character class.

At the left of the @ sign, either assert a non word boundary or assert a whitespace boundary.

Note that you don't have to escape the dot and the hyphen in the character class.

```
\B@\.?[\w.-]{2,}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zm9K50/1)

Another option:

```
(?<!\S)@\.?[\w.-]{2,}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oZp6wB/1)

Example

```
import re
 
pattern = r"(?<!\S)@\.?\w+[\w.-]{2,}"
s = "george want@to play @.hdgska football @dddada"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['@.hdgska', '@dddada']
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Is there any way to adopt my regex to face the problem that I have? Because there are some more options that I want to catch that I didn't mention them in the post.

Comment: @JohnAngelopoulos The patterns are for the current issue in the question. What other options do you mean?

Comment: Is there any way to adopt your regex (pattern = r"(?<!\S)@\.?\w+[\w.-]{2,}") to catch words like this @.-skdhdga?

Comment: @JohnAngelopoulos The pattern already matches that string, see https://regex101.com/r/4soMOs/1

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. There is one more thing that I don't know how to deal with, if you have time please check the edit in the post and let me know.

Comment: @JohnAngelopoulos Like this? `(?<!\S)@\.?\w+[\w.-]{2,}(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/6TQEGT/1